# Fetching Bans with Discord.JS

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make my ban count appear in a embed and I am struggling with it. Here is the code:

````
const log = new Hyperz.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle('Ban Database')
   .setColor('#FE2E2E')
   .setDescription(`Member Tag: <@${memberbannedid}>\nMember ID: ${memberbannedid}\nTotal Bans: ${message.guild.fetchBans()}`)
   .setFooter('Ban Database of DevGuard')

message.guild.channels.cache.get('818633337320767548').send(log)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchBans()` returns a collection (once resolved), You are trying to print out the entire collection. To get the count use `Collection#size`

As [Cameron R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14382706/cameron-r) pointed out, `Guild#fetchBans()` returns a promise. You will need to resolve the promise first inorder to get the size. Make sure you are in an async function if you plan to use the await method.

```
const fetchedBans = await message.guild.fetchBans();

//... Your Embed
.setDescription(`Member Tag: <@${memberbannedid}>\nMember ID: ${memberbannedid}\nTotal Bans: ${fetchedBans.size}`)
```

Comment: Appreciate the response but I am getting: undefined

Comment: Can you log `message.guild.fetchBans()` and see what you get

Comment: I do not get any errors in the console in Discord this is what it says: https://gyazo.com/dbe2f2826181eb579179e9bd16f50225

Comment: fetchBans returns a promise, you need to await the result of the promise in order to find its size

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I have edited my answer with the promise handling.